# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in Django and DRF when saving data to model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to save a file to the Django instance the following way:

```
class SomeName(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        file = serializer.validated_data["file"]

        object = fileUpload.objects.create(
            file_local_storage=file,
            file=file,
        )
```

.....

The models is

```
class fileUpload(models.Model):

    fileName = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(storage=PrivateMediaStorage())
    file_local_storage = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/", blank=True)
```

The error I get is

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file in Django and DRF when wrting
> data

Comment: Can you add the content of the `fileUploadSerializer` here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file-saving logic in serializer, not in view

```
class SomeName(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = fileUpload.objects.all()
    serializer_class = fileUploadSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In serializer,

```
class fileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upload_file = serializers.FileField(
        max_length = 1000000, allow_empty_file = False, write_only = True)
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ('upload_file ', 'media', 'file', 'file_local_storage')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'file': {'read_only': True},
            'file_local_storage': {'read_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        file_data = validated_data.pop('upload_file')
        fileUploadObj = fileUpload(**validated_data)
        fileUploadObj.file = file_data
        fileUploadObj.file_local_storage = file_data
        fileUploadObj.save()
        return fileUploadObj
```

And in frontend, you should upload a file with the key named `upload_file`, not `file`.